# mysql field not being updated with date now()

Tags: mysql

I seem to have a syntax/logic error in the following query.  They 'dateupdate' field is not setting current date with the NOW() function.

What am I doing wrong?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE SET `affiliate_url` = '".$item['affiliate_url']."',
 `image_url` = '".$item['image_url']."', `price` = '".$item['price']."', 
`price_sale` = '".$item['price_sale']."', 
`percentOff` = '".$item['percentOff']."', `merchant` = '".$item['merchant']."', 
`dateupdate` = NOW() WHERE  
`prosp_rawdata`.`productId` = '".$item['productId']."'");
```

Comment: What is the issue with `now()` you are getting?

Comment: What is the format of the column dateupdate ? Are the other fields updated ?

Comment: Type:  timestamp  Default: Null

Comment: What is the `syntax/logic error in the following query`?

Comment: where are you specifying the table that you want to update?

Comment: This was the error.  Thank you Martin.